# Add execution finished time on karma config

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm using Karma for my tests and I would like to know if there is a way to print on the console the time of the tests execution has ended?

Something like:

```
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Mac OS X 10.11.6): Executed 126 of 126 SUCCESS (3.516 secs / 3.087 secs)
TOTAL: 126 SUCCESS

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 23.06% ( 1900/8238 ), 118 ignored
Branches     : 16.29% ( 594/3646 ), 160 ignored
Functions    : 23.93% ( 589/2461 ), 77 ignored
Lines        : 18.04% ( 1359/7532 )
================================================================================

Executed: 08-24-2016 11:34:59
Finished: 08-24-2016 11:35:42
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use karma coverage and karma spec reporter.

Add in package.json:

```
"karma-coverage": "1.1.0", 
"karma-spec-reporter" : "0.0.26"
```

And then in your karma conf:

```
reporters: ['spec, 'coverage'],
```

Config part: (from docs)

[spec docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-spec-reporter)

```
  specReporter: {
    maxLogLines: 5,         // limit number of lines logged per test 
    suppressErrorSummary: true,  // do not print error summary 
    suppressFailed: false,  // do not print information about failed tests 
    suppressPassed: false,  // do not print information about passed tests 
    suppressSkipped: true,  // do not print information about skipped tests 
    showSpecTiming: true// print the time elapsed for each spec 
  },
  coverageReporter: {
    type: 'html',
    dir: 'release/coverage/'
  }
```

You will get a printout similar to your request and a coverage report in the release/coverage directory.

Comment: sorry, Did you get my question? I have this output except of the two lines at the end... that's my request. How do I add these lines? How I inject custom prints to the console?

Comment: The only plugin I know that will do that is the spec reporter one. And enable showSpecTiming. Your question just said "I want something like", so I tried to get that in full.